# Equivalent topologies on discrete space

Tags: general-topology

How to solve the following:

If $Y$ is discrete, prove that $C(Y,X)=X^Y$ and $\tau_{co}=\tau=\tau_{C(Y,X)}$,where  $\tau_{co}$ is compact open topology, $\tau$ is Tikhonov (product) topology and $\tau_{C(X,Y)}$ is induced topology on $C(Y,X)$.

(Generally, $\tau_{C(Y,X)}\subset\tau_{co}$ and $\tau_{C(Y,X)}\subset\tau$. But, why converse inclusions also hold? How to prove that? Is this conclusion okay: Y is compact, then the compact subsets are finite ones, so convergence in $\tau_{co}$ is the same as convergence in $\tau_{C(X,Y)}$?)

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take the time to think about it. This is easy, all of it follows pretty much from the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement here is that

> all functions $Y\to X$ are continuous if $Y$ is *discrete*.

$Y$ is not compact (if infinite), but the main point is that its compact subsets are *exactly* the finite ones.